# usb 2-6: unable to read config error -71

Tags: ubuntu, linux-kernel, usb

## How do i sort the error below:

[    4.138395] usb 2-6: unable to read config index 0 descriptor/start: -71
[    4.138400] usb 2-6: can't read configurations, error -71

## My Linux system info

Linux 5.3.0-53-generic #47~18.04.1-Ubuntu SMP Thu May 7 13:10:50 UTC 2020 x86_64 x86_64 x86_64 GNU/Linux

## My dmesg detailed output is below

`dmesg | grep "usb"
[    0.228796] usbcore: registered new interface driver usbfs
[    0.228796] usbcore: registered new interface driver hub
[    0.228796] usbcore: registered new device driver usb
[    0.284021] pci 0000:00:1d.0: quirk_usb_early_handoff+0x0/0x6a0 took 17043 usecs
[    1.096023] usb usb1: New USB device found, idVendor=1d6b, idProduct=0002, bcdDevice= 5.03
[    1.096025] usb usb1: New USB device strings: Mfr=3, Product=2, SerialNumber=1
[    1.096026] usb usb1: Product: EHCI Host Controller
[    1.096028] usb usb1: Manufacturer: Linux 5.3.0-53-generic ehci_hcd
[    1.096029] usb usb1: SerialNumber: 0000:00:1d.0
[    1.097817] usb usb2: New USB device found, idVendor=1d6b, idProduct=0002, bcdDevice= 5.03
[    1.097818] usb usb2: New USB device strings: Mfr=3, Product=2, SerialNumber=1
[    1.097820] usb usb2: Product: xHCI Host Controller
[    1.097821] usb usb2: Manufacturer: Linux 5.3.0-53-generic xhci-hcd
[    1.097822] usb usb2: SerialNumber: 0000:00:14.0
[    1.098360] usb usb3: New USB device found, idVendor=1d6b, idProduct=0003, bcdDevice= 5.03
[    1.098362] usb usb3: New USB device strings: Mfr=3, Product=2, SerialNumber=1
[    1.098363] usb usb3: Product: xHCI Host Controller
[    1.098364] usb usb3: Manufacturer: Linux 5.3.0-53-generic xhci-hcd
[    1.098366] usb usb3: SerialNumber: 0000:00:14.0
[    1.431951] usb 2-3: new high-speed USB device number 2 using xhci_hcd
[    1.431954] usb 1-1: new high-speed USB device number 2 using ehci-pci
[    1.460560] usb 1-1: New USB device found, idVendor=8087, idProduct=8000, bcdDevice= 0.04
[    1.460563] usb 1-1: New USB device strings: Mfr=0, Product=0, SerialNumber=0
[    1.560031] usb 2-3: New USB device found, idVendor=064e, idProduct=e330, bcdDevice= 1.00
[    1.560034] usb 2-3: New USB device strings: Mfr=3, Product=1, SerialNumber=0
[    1.560035] usb 2-3: Product: HD WebCam
[    1.560037] usb 2-3: Manufacturer: SuYin
[    1.691932] usb 2-4: new full-speed USB device number 3 using xhci_hcd
[    1.841154] usb 2-4: New USB device found, idVendor=8087, idProduct=07dc, bcdDevice= 0.01
[    1.841156] usb 2-4: New USB device strings: Mfr=0, Product=0, SerialNumber=0
[    1.967949] usb 2-6: new full-speed USB device number 4 using xhci_hcd
[    4.138395] usb 2-6: unable to read config index 0 descriptor/start: -71
[    4.138400] usb 2-6: can't read configurations, error -71
[    4.263952] usb 2-6: new full-speed USB device number 5 using xhci_hcd
[    6.434721] usb 2-6: unable to read config index 0 descriptor/start: -71
[    6.434725] usb 2-6: can't read configurations, error -71
[    6.434776] usb usb2-port6: attempt power cycle
[    7.083950] usb 2-6: new full-speed USB device number 6 using xhci_hcd
[    9.126309] usb 2-6: unable to read config index 0 descriptor/start: -71
[    9.126313] usb 2-6: can't read configurations, error -71
[    9.251953] usb 2-6: new full-speed USB device number 7 using xhci_hcd
[   16.459984] usb 2-6: unable to read config index 0 descriptor/start: -110
[   16.459989] usb 2-6: can't read configurations, error -110
[   16.460036] usb usb2-port6: unable to enumerate USB device
[   16.587955] usb 2-7: new low-speed USB device number 8 using xhci_hcd
[   16.739163] usb 2-7: New USB device found, idVendor=275d, idProduct=0ba6, bcdDevice= 1.00
[   16.739165] usb 2-7: New USB device strings: Mfr=0, Product=1, SerialNumber=0
[   16.739167] usb 2-7: Product: USB OPTICAL MOUSE 
[   17.011950] usb 2-6: new full-speed USB device number 9 using xhci_hcd
[   19.181537] usb 2-6: unable to read config index 0 descriptor/start: -71
[   19.181542] usb 2-6: can't read configurations, error -71
[   19.307952] usb 2-6: new full-speed USB device number 10 using xhci_hcd
[   21.477867] usb 2-6: unable to read config index 0 descriptor/start: -71
[   21.477871] usb 2-6: can't read configurations, error -71
[   21.477920] usb usb2-port6: attempt power cycle
[   22.127954] usb 2-6: new full-speed USB device number 11 using xhci_hcd
[   24.169499] usb 2-6: unable to read config index 0 descriptor/start: -71
[   24.169503] usb 2-6: can't read configurations, error -71
[   24.295954] usb 2-6: new full-speed USB device number 12 using xhci_hcd
[   26.338314] usb 2-6: unable to read config index 0 descriptor/start: -71
[   26.338318] usb 2-6: can't read configurations, error -71
[   26.338363] usb usb2-port6: unable to enumerate USB device
[   26.344720] usbcore: registered new interface driver usbhid
[   26.344721] usbhid: USB HID core driver
[   26.346836] input: USB OPTICAL MOUSE  as /devices/pci0000:00/0000:00:14.0/usb2/2-7/2-7:1.0/0003:275D:0BA6.0001/input/input7
[   26.347026] hid-generic 0003:275D:0BA6.0001: input,hidraw0: USB HID v1.11 Mouse [USB OPTICAL MOUSE ] on usb-0000:00:14.0-7/input0
[   26.647945] usb 2-6: new full-speed USB device number 13 using xhci_hcd
[   28.817221] usb 2-6: unable to read config index 0 descriptor/start: -71
[   28.817226] usb 2-6: can't read configurations, error -71
[   28.943977] usb 2-6: new full-speed USB device number 14 using xhci_hcd
[   31.114079] usb 2-6: unable to read config index 0 descriptor/start: -71
[   31.114083] usb 2-6: can't read configurations, error -71
[   31.114126] usb usb2-port6: attempt power cycle
[   31.763948] usb 2-6: new full-speed USB device number 15 using xhci_hcd
[   33.805850] usb 2-6: unable to read config index 0 descriptor/start: -71
[   33.805854] usb 2-6: can't read configurations, error -71
[   33.935930] usb 2-6: new full-speed USB device number 16 using xhci_hcd
[   35.977159] usb 2-6: unable to read config index 0 descriptor/start: -71
[   35.977163] usb 2-6: can't read configurations, error -71
[   35.977209] usb usb2-port6: unable to enumerate USB device
[   36.287947] usb 2-6: new full-speed USB device number 17 using xhci_hcd
[   38.469597] usb 2-6: unable to read config index 0 descriptor/start: -71
[   38.469602] usb 2-6: can't read configurations, error -71
[   38.595937] usb 2-6: new full-speed USB device number 18 using xhci_hcd
[   40.769529] usb 2-6: unable to read config index 0 descriptor/start: -71
[   40.769534] usb 2-6: can't read configurations, error -71
[   40.769583] usb usb2-port6: attempt power cycle
[   41.419957] usb 2-6: new full-speed USB device number 19 using xhci_hcd
[   43.460322] usb 2-6: unable to read config index 0 descriptor/start: -71
[   43.460327] usb 2-6: can't read configurations, error -71
[   43.587905] usb 2-6: new full-speed USB device number 20 using xhci_hcd
[   45.632993] usb 2-6: unable to read config index 0 descriptor/start: -71
[   45.632996] usb 2-6: can't read configurations, error -71
[   45.633026] usb usb2-port6: unable to enumerate USB device
[   45.943905] usb 2-6: new full-speed USB device number 21 using xhci_hcd
[   48.117157] usb 2-6: unable to read config index 0 descriptor/start: -71
[   48.117160] usb 2-6: can't read configurations, error -71
[   48.247893] usb 2-6: new full-speed USB device number 22 using xhci_hcd
[   50.420700] usb 2-6: unable to read config index 0 descriptor/start: -71
[   50.420706] usb 2-6: can't read configurations, error -71
[   50.420765] usb usb2-port6: attempt power cycle
[   51.071932] usb 2-6: new full-speed USB device number 23 using xhci_hcd
[   51.093404] usb 2-6: New USB device found, idVendor=04f3, idProduct=0085, bcdDevice= 0.20
[   51.093407] usb 2-6: New USB device strings: Mfr=4, Product=14, SerialNumber=0
[   51.093408] usb 2-6: Product: Touchscreen
[   51.093409] usb 2-6: Manufacturer: ELAN
[   51.100449] input: ELAN Touchscreen as /devices/pci0000:00/0000:00:14.0/usb2/2-6/2-6:1.0/0003:04F3:0085.0002/input/input16
[   51.100566] input: ELAN Touchscreen as /devices/pci0000:00/0000:00:14.0/usb2/2-6/2-6:1.0/0003:04F3:0085.0002/input/input17
[   51.100620] input: ELAN Touchscreen as /devices/pci0000:00/0000:00:14.0/usb2/2-6/2-6:1.0/0003:04F3:0085.0002/input/input18
[   51.100735] hid-generic 0003:04F3:0085.0002: input,hiddev0,hidraw1: USB HID v1.10 Device [ELAN Touchscreen] on usb-0000:00:14.0-6/input0
[   52.134419] input: ELAN Touchscreen as /devices/pci0000:00/0000:00:14.0/usb2/2-6/2-6:1.0/0003:04F3:0085.0002/input/input20
[   52.134576] hid-multitouch 0003:04F3:0085.0002: input,hiddev0,hidraw1: USB HID v1.10 Device [ELAN Touchscreen] on usb-0000:00:14.0-6/input0
[   52.837522] usbcore: registered new interface driver btusb
[   52.992325] input: HD WebCam: HD WebCam as /devices/pci0000:00/0000:00:14.0/usb2/2-3/2-3:1.0/input/input24
[   52.992419] usbcore: registered new interface driver uvcvideo`